# SQL PHP Search column name with value

Tags: php, sql

Ok so I have a db of Users (ID) and their T or F results to different Hobbies.  So something like this, excuse the formating I didn't know how to space it.

```
ID   | swimming | running | rock climbing | learning to program.

user1       T         F            T                  T

user2       F         T            T                  F
```

OK I wanted to do a SQL search where I return all Column names of a table, if the value of that column is "T" where the ID is the users ID.

so if the ID is user1, I return swimming, rock climbing, learning to program.

Now I couldn't figure out how to do this with SQL so I figured I could try do this manually with PHP.

So I tried something like this.

```
 $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT swimming, running, rock, 
 program FROM mytablehere WHERE ID = ?");
 $stmt->bind_param("s", $ID);  // specific ID is went in via here
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->bind_result( $swimming, $running, $rock, $program);
        $stmt->fetch(); 
        $user = array();
 if($swimming == "T"){
 $swimming ="swimming";
 $user['swimming'] = $swimming; }
  ...
return $user;
```

So the idea is it would find the binds that are "T" and insert them into the user array, and leave the ones that are "F" out.

However my postman tells me, no data is found.
So my question is how do do I get this sort of function.  Is there an SQL search to make this easier or how do I need to approach my PHP code differently.
Can I not if then the bind $swimming or do I have to bind them all to one array, and then return a different array at the end?

Comment: Any column names with spaces in them will need backticks round them.

Comment: those are just examples, to make it clearer they aren't the column names. Like Rock Climbing is actually rc.  It just makes no sense when it's posted as rc

Answer (score 0):

```
if($user['swimming'] == "T"){
    $hobby['swimming'] = "swimming"; }

  return $hobby
```

there should really be an easier way to do this.  If anyone has an sql search that would be great.  But this will allow you to do it via php.  I was having issues with my postman which was stopping me from getting data, but once I did the code up top will just give you an useless mess.  This will return only the column names but it has to be done manually.